# Limit text to x number of lines and append '...'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, typography

I am looking for a Javascript/jQuery + CSS way to limit a text (for example a product name) to *say, 2 lines*. But the visitors need to know that it is truncated and therefore I will need to append '...' at the end.

The original way I thought of doing this was to put the text in 1 line, measure the width of it and cut it off just before the text reaches *2 times the width of the containing div*, but it seems tricky as each character probably needs to be caculated for its width rather than that.

Limiting it to number of characters or words will not work in this case - I would like to fully fill the 2 lines of that div every time, instead of having gaps.

Is there a nice way to achieve this instead of using a monospaced font?

Comment: If you're using jQuery just grab this plugin: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: @elclanrs thanks! please submit as answer

Comment: OK, I added another plugin that I've used before with success.

Comment: The english term for 'dot dot dot' is **ellipsis**.

Comment: @Marko thanks, that will come in handy one day

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery try these plugins:

- http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/
- https://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/
- https://github.com/theproductguy/ThreeDots
- https://github.com/jjenzz/jquery.ellipsis

Comment: Hmm... ~600 LOC and an external dependency seems a bit over the top for those three little dots. Here's a quick POJS solution in about 20 lines. It needs a bit of work, need to crawl through siblings and find text nodes instead of making assumptions, and maybe some decent event handling, but I can't see this growing over 50 LOC... http://jsfiddle.net/HERuT/

Comment: That looks good actually. But Autoellipsis (my plugin of choice) is [barely 200 lines without comments](https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/5529573), I'd say that's good enough if you're already using jQuery.

Comment: Autoellipsis did look much cleaner to me too, but I didn't take a very close look at it. I think the thing that bothers me about these kind of scripts is the perceived need for jQuery; seems like when you're doing DOM-intensive stuff like this, you might as well get rid of dependencies and just write the extra event handling code or whatever yourself... seems like 99% of jQuery is not needed for a script like this. Autoellipsis certainly looked like the better candidate for possibly becoming a POJS script.

Comment: still not clear how to have 2 lines (!) ellipsed... dotdotdot controls the height, not lines number by eg....

Answer (score 1):

We can use css for this:

```
.truncate {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block; /* for links */
}
```

Comment: Except it only works for a single line of text, not, say, two lines of text.